# Ubuntu 16.06 Unable to locate package msodbcsql

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, msodbcsql17

I'm trying to install the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on my Ubuntu 16.04. I've already done

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
```

and

```
apt-get update
```

and it looks correct. Now I'm doing `ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17` and I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql17
```

In general for last few hours I'm doing my best to connect from PHP to MSSQL Server but something is wrong and I'm running out of ideal what could be wrong. I check a lot of tutorials and in each of them it's working. I'm sure that I missed something, but I don't know what. Could you please help me with this?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you download the key first? [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yes I did, just like in your link `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -` I received 'OK'.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't updated the package listeing then.

Comment: Do you mean `curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list`? If yes- I did. After this I did `apt-get update` and package msodbcsql17 is not located.

Comment: after `apt-get update` I had something like this: `Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease [4003 B]   
Get:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial/main amd64 Packages [111 kB]
Fetched 224 kB in 2s (110 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done`

Comment: Any luck with `apt-cache search msodbc`? (if you haven't fixed this yet). Also consider taking this over to askubuntu.com, which is also a stackexchange site that is more appropriate for this question.

Comment: Today I've installed msodbcsql on another Ubuntu based server and there was no problem. I have no idea why. It is highly possible that there was a mess in configuration of previous server. I took it over from the previous admin and I don't have 100% knowledge what was he doing with it. Anyway thank you for your the tips.